# Multiple pages in a single window C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a control that allows to choose data, that should be in it? For example: red one - static page, blue is dynamic, below are buttons that allow to switch pages in dynamic part.
[image]

Comment: The "dynamic" part sounds like a typical `TabControl` to me... You can use mutliple controls - one "static" *and* one "dynamic" (e.g. `TabControl`). You just have to put them inside a Container control (e.g. `DockPanel`)

Answer (score 1):

I use the dockpanel suite for this:

[dockpanel suite](http://dockpanelsuite.com/)

This contol is designed to mimic the vs.net tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `ContentControl` databound to a property on your `UserControl`. Change the property when you want to update the content. Ensure that the property is either and `DependencyProperty` or that your user control implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is achived by using DataTemplates. You just bind the *SelectedItem* of the "red" control (e.g. a ListView) to the *Content* of the "blue" Control (it should be a ContentPresenter).
You add DataTemplates to the Resources accessable by the "blue" control which will then display different content depending on the underlaying class/data.